# Unable to connect XMPP server with ASmack in Android

Tags: android, asmack

I have a fully working Chat Client that I made in Java. Now I'm looking forward to implement the same on my android device. I started off with importing the ASmack Library in my project and I'm checking at each phase to avoid errors. I'm stuck at the very first step though. My Activity is not able to find the class in ASmack Jar, hence I assume I'm unable to proceed.

**My Simple code :**

```
package com.test.mypro;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "TESTER";
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        TextView tvHello;
        XMPPConnection connection;
        ConnectionConfiguration config;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "I'm here");
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration("prc.p1.im", 5222, "prc.p1.im");
            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            try {
                connection.connect();
                // tvHello.setText("Connected to XMPP server");
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Successfully Connected");
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Not Connected");
            }
        }
    }
```

**LogCat Logs:**

```
12-22 15:58:16.319: E/dalvikvm(828): Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method com.test.mypro.TestProjectActivity.onCreate
12-22 15:58:16.339: W/dalvikvm(828): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 26 (Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration;) in Lcom/test/mypro/TestProjectActivity;
12-22 15:58:16.339: D/dalvikvm(828): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0019
12-22 15:58:16.351: D/dalvikvm(828): VFY: dead code 0x001b-0047 in Lcom/test/mypro/TestProjectActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
12-22 15:58:16.509: I/TESTER(828): I'm here
12-22 15:58:16.519: D/AndroidRuntime(828): Shutting down VM
12-22 15:58:16.519: W/dalvikvm(828): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.test.mypro.TestProjectActivity.onCreate(TestProjectActivity.java:24)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-22 15:58:16.561: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Additional Info :** I have asmack-android-7.jar library imported. My AVD is running 2.3.3 Android.

I assume owing to this I'm getting the fatal exception.
What am I missing here? Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ChatScreen extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener { 

private final static String SERVER_HOST = "192.168.88.158";
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
private final static String SERVICE_NAME = "192.168.88.158";
private final static String LOGIN = "manish";
private final static String PASSWORD = "android";
private List<String> m_discussionThread;
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_discussionThreadAdapter;
private XMPPConnection m_connection;
private Handler m_handler;
public static  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;
Presence presence;
ListView list;
int position = 0;

private Button BackBtn;
private Button EndChatBtn;
TextView opretor;
    String opretorName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_screen);
    usersList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    opretorName = intent.getStringExtra("opName");
    opretor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Opretor1);
    opretor.setText(opretorName);
            m_handler = new Handler();
    try {
        initConnection();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final EditText recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
    recipient.setText(opretorName + "@manishsys-pc");
    final EditText message = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.message);        
    list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.thread);

    m_discussionThread = new ArrayList<String>();
    m_discussionThreadAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, m_discussionThread);
    list.setAdapter(m_discussionThreadAdapter);

    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = recipient.getText().toString();
            String text = message.getText().toString();

            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM d, hh:mm a");
            String strdt= formatter.format(c.getTime());
            msg.setBody(text);
            m_connection.sendPacket(msg);
            m_discussionThread.add("me :" + strdt);
            m_discussionThread.add(text);
            m_discussionThreadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    BackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChatBackBtn);
    BackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    EndChatBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.EndChatBtn);
    EndChatBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initConnection() throws XMPPException {
    //Initialisation de la connexion
    ConnectionConfiguration config =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME );
    m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    m_connection.connect();
    m_connection.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    m_connection.sendPacket(presence);

    //Get all userList
    Roster roster = m_connection.getRoster();
    String[] urlArray = new String[] { "office" };
    roster.createEntry("ravi", "ravi", urlArray);
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

    for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

        Presence.Type type = presence.getType();       

        map.put("USER", entry.getName().toString());
        map.put("STATUS", type.toString());
        Log.e("USER", entry.getName().toString());

        usersList.add(map);
    }

 // Assume we've created a Connection name "connection".
    ChatManager chatmanager = m_connection.getChatManager();
    Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("mansih@manishsys-pc ", new MessageListener() {
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        }
    });

    try {
        newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
    }
    catch (XMPPException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
    }

    //enregistrement de l'écouteur de messages
    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    m_connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM d, hh:mm a");
                    String strdt= formatter.format(c.getTime());
                    m_discussionThread.add(fromName + ":" + strdt);
                    m_discussionThread.add(message.getBody());

                    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            list.smoothScrollToPosition(list.getCount()-1);
                            m_discussionThreadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ChatBackBtn:

        Intent BackIntent = new Intent(ChatScreen.this,
                OperatorScreen.class);
        BackIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(BackIntent);
        ChatScreen.this.finish();

        break;
    case R.id.EndChatBtn:

        Intent EndChtIntent = new Intent(ChatScreen.this,
                RatingScreen.class);
        EndChtIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(EndChtIntent);
        ChatScreen.this.finish();

        break;

    default:
        break;`
    }
  }
}
```

it's my code it work fine for me i hope it helpfull for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private final static String server_host = "talk.google.com";
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
private final static String SERVICE_NAME = "gmail.com";

ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration( server_host, SERVER_PORT , SERVICE_NAME);
        XMPPConnection m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
                try {
                     SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
                     config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);     
                     m_connection.connect();
                    Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: I think you didn't see the log properly. The main issue which you should take note of in the log is this -` Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method com.test.mypro.TestProjectActivity.onCreate `. I'm unable to call the COnnectionConfiguration class. Nonetheless I tried out your code, getting the same result

Comment: Please check the log. The issue somewhere lies in the import of the library I assume(the first line of the log). It is unable to pull out the ConnectionConfiguration class which will initiate the further process for connection hence putting it in a separate method shouldn't really make any difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you Nagarjuna for your time and replies. I have posted the relevant answer and the issue is solved.

Comment: see here as asmack library it is working perfect http://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/detail?name=asmack-2010.05.07.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. It was owing to the update I made to the API. I deleted the imported ASmack library from my project property. The Lib folder was missing too. Hence I made one folder ("libs") int he project and pasted the ASmack jar there. BY cleaning the project once, the error was fixed.
 Thank you.
 [Reference](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)

Comment: Please don't only provide a link to the solution. Instead describe here what helped you solving the problem.

Comment: I have added the details to the solution. Thanks.