# AndroidConnectionConfiguration class not found Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am using Android-Studio for connecting to Openfire( XMPP ) and Asmack. Sample code is

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, 5222);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
try {
connection.connect();
Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+connection.getHost());
} catch (XMPPException ex) {
    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());                                                                           Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
    setConnection(null);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
} catch (SmackException ex) {
    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
}
```

I am getting this error

```
.xmpp E/XMPPChatDemoActivity﹕ [SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to null
E/XMPPChatDemoActivity﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException
E/XMPPChatDemoActivity﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
```

which clearly means connection.getHost() is null. Lots of people are saying to use

```
 AndroidConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(HOST,PORT, SERVICE);
```

insted of ConnectionCOnfiguration. But there is not class which named AndroidConnectionConfiguration.

I am using Android Studio and Asmack asmack-android-8-4.0.6.jar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002092/unable-to-connect-xmpp-server-with-asmack-in-android
Do you check this answear?

Comment: @hilsofbeard Yes but thats not working me as well ..... seems like jar's version issue here